# JQuery Mobile 1.0 - Self-posting pages causing duplicate dialogs or history entries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

If you go to http://jsbin.com/ibozun/2, hit "Add Item," and then hit "Save," you will see that a second dialog is opened on top of the first one.  The form in the dialog is posting to itself (no action defined) - this is by design.  Because the dialog has duplicated itself, now you have to hit "Cancel" 2 times to get it to close.

The use-case for this setup is a MS MVC3 page with unobtrusive JQuery validation on it.  The default scripts (in other words, I have no custom validators - the scripts are straight from MS) cause an ajax call to the server, and JQM treats that the same as a self-posting form - so you wind up with a duplicate dialog if validation fails.

A similar thing happens if the second page as a page, rather than a dialog - the form posting to itself results in a second history entry in the browser, so to get back to page 1, you have to hit back 2 times.

I believed this be a bug in JQM, but after submitting a bug on GitHub, I was told that this is the expected behavior.  So, assuming this behavior that will not be changing in the framework, how do I prevent this from happening for my instance (preferring NOT to edit the framework JS)?  Do I have to write my own ajax calls for validation so that I can prevent JQM from knowing that anything has happened?  That seems unfortunate...

One idea I had was to detect that the nextPage and current page are the same on "pageHide", and manipulate the dialog/history myself, but have had no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no dialog duplication in the example. Second, my response and an explanation as to why solving the history issues with posting back to the same page for users of the library is hard can be found [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3227#issuecomment-3037142). This example is particularly thorny because it's also in a dialog which we don't support linking to, so disabling ajax for the form (ie forcing it to reload), which would work if it were embedded in a page, won't serve.

The quick solution here is to switch the dialog to a page and add the `data-ajax=false` data attribute to the form. Mind you this causes a page flash/reload and requires that the form document be fully formed with a `head` including javascript,css, etc.

Comment: Accepting as the answer, but as you can see from the rest of the thread linked to by nickel, this isn't a completed conversation :).  Unfortunately, using data-ajax=false is problematic for another reason: that kicks iPad out of "App Mode" when running the mobile site from an icon saved to the home screen.  For now, we're just using unobtrusive jquery validation as much as possible, which reduces the duplication (or "virtual" duplication, if that's more accurate).

Comment: jkane001 hopefully we'll have a solution for you within the next release (It's on my radar)